# Most efficient way to save tile data of an isometric game

Tags: javascript, isometric

I'm working on an isometric game for fast browsers that support `<canvas>`, which is great fun. To save information of each tile, I use a two-dimensional array which contains numbers representing tile IDs, like:

```
var level = [[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0],
             [0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1],
             [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]];

var tiles = [
    {name: 'grass',  color: 'green'},
    {name: 'water',  color: 'blue'},
    {name: 'forest', color: 'ForestGreen'}
];
```

So far it works great, but now I want to work with heights and slopes like in this picture:
[alt text http://harmen.no-ip.org/isometrictiles.png](http://harmen.no-ip.org/isometrictiles.png)

For each tile I need to save it's tile ID, height and information about which corners are turned upward.

I came up with a simple idea about a bitwise representation of all four corners, like this:

```
1011 // top, bottom and left corner turned up
```

My question is: what is the most efficient way to save these three values for each cell? Is it possible to save these three values as one integer?

Comment: +1 for the picture :)

Comment: +1 Excellent question.  Interested in the game as well.

Comment: +1 for not only the picture but the overall clarity of the question. It's really nice to see someone who takes their time in thoroughly asking a question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are trying to do something like the picture you don't need to store which corners are up/down as it can be deduced from the surrounding tiles.

For example if the current tile is height `n` and the height of the tile one up from the current tile is height `n+1` then the current tile must have "top corner up"

> Great! Thank you! I'll try to implement this. One more thought to complete your answer: is it possible to store height and tile ID as an integer?

Yes. You will need to use [Bitwise Operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

If you divided the integer equally between height and id using the first 16 bits for height and the rest of id

```
var id = tile & 0x0000FFFF; //mask the first 16 bits
var height = tile >>> 16; //shift the first 16 bits to the right
```

Setting can be done in a similar mannar

```
tile &= 0xFFFF0000; //remove id bits
tile |= id; //set new id

tile &= 0x0000FFFF; //remove height bits
tile |= (height << 16);
```

Comment: +1, but store corner heights rather than cell heights, to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Great! Thank you! I'll try to implement this. One more thought to complete your answer: is it possible to store `height` and `tile ID` as an integer?

Comment: Great solution. Though, more CPU expensive than storing the heights of each corner. (To determine height of all corners, it should do 9 height-lookups, with their bit shifts.)

Comment: @Pindatjuh Depending on the landscape allowed, it is quite probable that only 4 lookups would be required. The example above would only use require 4 which would give it a space advantage over storing the height of each vertex

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can:

```
var corners = 11; // binary 1011;
var topCornerUp = corners & 0x8;
var bottomCornerUp = corners & 0x2;
```

If you want to optimize it, though, consider what [Yacoby said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566531/most-efficient-way-to-save-tile-data-of-an-isometric-game/2566538#2566538) - you could store an array of the corners instead of saving them separately for each tile.

Answer (score 0):

If the height is in the [0, 255] range you can save 4 heights in a single integer using bit manipulation. In hex:

0xAABBCCDD, AA = first height, BB = second, etc..

To get the left-most height you would do `((0xAABBCCDD & 0xFF000000) >> 24) & 0xFF`, which returns 170 (0xAA).

To set it: `integer &= (0x00FFFFFF); /* Clear the value */ integer |= (height << 24);`

Comment: You can certainly do that, but remember that Javascript uses floating point for all numbers, so the efficiency you'd get in C++ or whatever really wouldn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

Is the area rectangular? If it is you could simply store width and height of the area, tile length and an array of integers representing the vertex heights.